# Prisma nested create throws unknown arg error while prisma example works

Tags: javascript, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I have some troubles with prisma nested create. The second nested create does not work as it complains that that arg does not exist. If I write the nested create manually, I can see it with typescript that "audio" field is optional and exists on that model.

Here is the model

```
model CulturalHeritage {
  id                     Int                      @id @default(autoincrement())
  duration               Int
  categoryId             Int
  category               CulturalHeritageCategory @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  published              Boolean                  @default(true)
  mediaId                Int?
  media                  Media?                    @relation(fields: [mediaId], references: [id])
  created                DateTime                 @default(now())
  updated                DateTime?                @updatedAt
  expired                DateTime?
  CulturalHeritageLocale CulturalHeritageLocale[]
  MediaCulturalHeritage  MediaCulturalHeritage[]
  CulturalHeritageExibit CulturalHeritageExibit[]
}

model CulturalHeritageLocale {
  id                 Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  culturalHeritageId Int
  culturalHeritage   CulturalHeritage @relation(fields: [culturalHeritageId], references: [id])
  description        String           @default("<p></p>")
  title              String
  audio              Media?           @relation(fields: [audioId], references: [id])
  audioText          String?
  audioId            Int?
  localeFlag         LocaleFlag       @relation(fields: [localeFlagId], references: [id])
  localeFlagId       Int
  created            DateTime         @default(now())
  updated            DateTime?        @updatedAt
  expired            DateTime?
}


model Media {
  id                     Int                      @id @default(autoincrement())
  path                   String
  extension              String
  name                   String
  type                   String
  size                   Int
  created                DateTime                 @default(now())
  updated                DateTime?                @updatedAt
  expired                DateTime?
  CulturalHeritage       CulturalHeritage[]
  CulturalHeritageLocale CulturalHeritageLocale[]
  ExibitLocale           ExibitLocale[]
  MediaExibit            MediaExibit[]
  MediaCulturalHeritage  MediaCulturalHeritage[]
}
```

Function:

```
//...
return await prisma.culturalHeritage.create({
              include: {
                media: true,
                CulturalHeritageLocale: {
                  include: {
                    audio: true,
                  },
                },
              },
              data: {
                duration: args.data.duration,
                category: { connect: { id: args.data.categoryId } },
                published: args.data.published,
                CulturalHeritageLocale: {
                  // create: args.localeData,
                  create: [
                    {
                      description: '<p>123</p>',
                      title: '123',
                      audioText: '',
                      localeFlagId: 2,
                    },
                    {
                      description: '<p>1</p>',
                      title: '1',
                      audio: { // <--- PRISMA ERROR HERE, TYPESCRIPTS STATES THAT ARG IS OPTIONAL AND EXISTS
                        create: {
                          name: 'file_example_OOG_1MG.ogg',
                          path: '163e6e51-7a6b-4d36-acf6-1328cdd87caf.ogg',
                          extension: 'ogg',
                          type: 'audio/ogg',
                          size: 1089524,
                        },
                      },
                      audioText: 'lll',
                      localeFlagId: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
                media: { create: args.data.media.create[0] },
              },
            });
```

Error:

```
Unknown arg `audio` in data.CulturalHeritageLocale.create.1.audio for type CulturalHeritageLocaleUncheckedCreateWithoutCulturalHeritageInput. Did you mean `audioId`? Available args:
type CulturalHeritageLocaleUncheckedCreateWithoutCulturalHeritageInput {
  id?: Int
  description?: String
  title: String
  audioText?: String | Null
  audioId?: Int | Null
  localeFlagId: Int
  created?: DateTime
  updated?: DateTime | Null
  expired?: DateTime | Null
}
```

[Prisma example:](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-a-single-record-and-multiple-related-records)

```
const user = await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    email: 'yvette@prisma.io',
    name: 'Yvette',
    posts: {
      create: [
        {
          title: 'How to make an omelette',
          categories: {
            create: { // <--- Works fine
              name: 'Easy cooking',
            },
          },
        },
        { title: 'How to eat an omelette' },
      ],
    },
  },
  include: {
    // Include posts
    posts: {
      include: {
        categories: true, // Include post categories
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Is it possible to write deeply nested create operation?
Do I need to use transaction for that?
Are there any alternatives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing `localeFlagId` directly, you need to pass it via `connect` like this:

```
localeFlag: { connect: { id: 1 } }
```

Comment: You are correct! using connect instead of direct id solved the issue with nested create. The error was quite misleading. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, we working on creating a better error message for that :)